# How to Use DBInstanceID from the ROS to query the database urls by Aliyun CLI

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ros

I am trying to work with Alibaba Cloud from Command line by use [Aliyun CLI](https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli) & [Aliyun ROS CLI](https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-ros-cli).

When creating a stack by ROS template, I got the outputs are `DBInstanceStatus` and `DBInstanceID`.

So How to Use DBInstanceID from the ROS to query the database URLs by Aliyun CLI?

One more question Can we do a backup restore the database with Aliyun CLI commands or not? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not query the MongoDB connection information by using ROS CLI. You should use MongoDB API:
[DescribeReplicaSetRole](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/62134.htm?spm=a3c0i.o62135en.b99.100.cb9af32R8WHy0) or [DescribeShardingNetworkAddress](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/62135.htm?spm=a3c0i.o62134en.b99.101.7dd8773degCOia)

The related python sdk is aliyun-python-sdk-dds

```
pip install aliyun-python-sdk-dds
```

https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-openapi-python-sdk/tree/master/aliyun-python-sdk-dds